# Extract multiple patterns from a text file and save it to a panda dataframe [python]

Tags: python, regex, pandas

my Text file looks like this

```
Description: Text 1 follows <br/> blah blah blah Cause: Cause Text 1 
follows here <br/>Description: Text 2 follows <br/> blah blah 
blah Cause: Cause Text 2 follows here<br/>Description: Text 3 follows <br/> 
blah blah blah Description: Text 4 follows <br/> blah blah 
blah Cause: Cause Text 4 follows<br/>
```

I want a panda dataframe that has all Descriptions and causes in a structured format for NLP

```
Description              Cause
Text 1 follows     Cause Text 1 follows here
Text 2 follows     Cause Text 2 follows here
Text 3 follows     
Text 4 follows     Cause Text 4 follows here
```

What I have done so far:

```
re.findall(r'Description:(.*?)<br/>',textfile)
re.findall(r'Cause:(.*?)<br/>',textfile)
```

But this does not let me match the Descriptions and causes when i try to create the larger dataframe!

Thank you for any input or direction to do the same. Very new to python!

Comment: Try [`r'(?s)Description:\s*(?P<Description>(?:(?!<br/>).)*)<br/>(?:(?:(?!Description:).)*?Cause:\s*(?P<Cause>(?:(?!<br/>).)*))?'`](https://regex101.com/r/bRIOev/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
r"Description:(.*?)<br/>(?:(?!Cause)(?!Description).)*(?:Cause:(.*?)<br/>)?"
```

If you use this regex, which matches both a `Description` *and* an optional `Cause`, it will ensure the pairings of descriptions and causes stay "zipped" properly.

```
data = re.findall(r"Description:(.*?)<br/>(?:(?!Cause)(?!Description).)*(?:Cause:(.*?)<br/>)?", textfile)
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=("Description", "Cause"))
```